# Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid. Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Im working on a small program on vb.net and the problem is ive got two textboxes Names and Age (which are arrays). and I'm trying try to make it so that if a name is entered and age isn't it will come up with "please enter age", without adding anything to the array, which have tried to but keep getting a error of "Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid". ill put my code below to see if you can see any problems.

PS I'm only a beginner. and thank you.
[Image of what I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao94U.png)

'store in array'
        Dim Ages As String
        Dim Surnames As String

```
    Surnames = txtNames.Text
    Ages = txtAge.Text


    If txtNames.Text = "" Then

        MsgBox("Enter Name ")
        txtNames.Focus()
        SystemValueAge = SystemValueAge - 1
        SystemValueName = SystemValueName - 1
        txtNames.Focus()

    ElseIf Ages < 1 Or Ages > 100 Then

        MsgBox("Please Enter Valid Age")

        SystemValueAge = SystemValueAge - 1
        SystemValueName = SystemValueName - 1
        txtAge.Focus()

    ElseIf txtAge.Text = "" Then

        MsgBox("Enter Age")
        SystemValueAge = SystemValueAge - 1
        SystemValueName = SystemValueName - 1
        txtAge.Focus()


    End If
```

Comment: `Ages` is a string. You cannot compare it to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to convert the `txtAge.Text` to an integer prior to performing the comparison. Also, make sure you put your `ElseIf txtAge.Text = "" Then` before the `Convert.toInt32(Ages) < 1 Or Convert.toInt32(Ages) > 100` as shown below:

```
ElseIf txtAge.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Enter Age")
    SystemValueAge = SystemValueAge - 1
    SystemValueName = SystemValueName - 1
    txtAge.Focus()

ElseIf Convert.toInt32(Ages) < 1 Or Convert.toInt32(Ages) > 100 Then
    MsgBox("Please Enter Valid Age")
    SystemValueAge = SystemValueAge - 1
    SystemValueName = SystemValueName - 1
    txtAge.Focus()
End If
```

Reason being that you'll need to insert the `ElseIf txtAge.Text = ""` first is because if the string is empty, then control will not go into the following `ElseIf` statement hence you will *not* get a `FormatException` exception.

As a side note, you should use `ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAge.Text)` rather than `ElseIf txtAge.Text = ""`.

Comment: Thank You its much Appreciated

Comment: Ok yep, but now its replacing the last item in the array with a invalid item